# Cypress throws Webpack compilation error when trying to run tests inside a reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, cypress

> Error: Webpack Compilation Error ./client/src/containers/Login.jsx
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Src/api' in
> '/Users/user/Documents/product-bots/client/src/containers' resolve
> 'Src/api' in
> '/Users/sathish/Documents/product-bots/client/src/containers'   Parsed
> request is a module   using description file:
> /Users/sathish/Documents/product-bots/client/package.json (relative
> path: ./src/containers)

I am trying to set up and run cypress inside a react.js app. There is an import statement in the app that says `import api from 'Src/api`. Cypress fails at this point and throws the above error.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Below is the test code

```
import Login from '../../../client/src/containers/Login'

describe('Login', () => {
  it('Tries login', () => {
    mount(<Login />)
    cy.get('.login-form').should('exist')
  })
})
```

The above code calls login.jsx which has the 'Src/api' import.

jsconfig.js:
`"paths": {"Src/*": ["src/*"] }`
webpack.config.js:
`alias: { Src: path.resolve(Paths.srcDir)`

Comment: Can you post your cypress test code? You should probably mock the `api` file content in order to avoid the error

Comment: This is just small POC. I have pasted in the question.

Comment: Also, the 'Src/api' is not an absolute path. Src is an alias here.

Comment: I have provided additional information in the question. @LucaPizzini

Comment: @GlebBahmutov can you please help me to resolve this issue?